# How to use jquery blockUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I want to use jQuery blockUI but on their [site](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) they have not given what js to include, what css to use. Can sombody please give me a example with complete js and css included to show how to use jQuery blockUI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need to do is loading the [BlockUI](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.blockUI.js) script after including jQuery.
It does not need any CSS to work.

See this fiddle for a most simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/4FhHK/

Comment: What version of jquery does this work with?  I'm using 1.10.4 and the blockUI function doesn't seem to be there.  If I do alert($) I can see the jquery object but aleret($.blockUI) shows as undefined.

Comment: Did you load the blockUI plugin? It's not part of jQuery itself.

Comment: I did not, that was the problem.  I'm now using the file marked as Version 2.70.0-2014.11.23.  I also upgraded to jquery 3.1.1.  But I am now having this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923667/jquery-blockui-doesnt-work-unless-i-show-an-alert-first?noredirect=1#comment71027993_41923667

Answer (score -1):

add [this file](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.blockUI.js) after the jQuery reference

and then use the commands.