# Showing a "loading" Message box asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, messagebox

I have an asp application,(online form) and all of the textboxes are disabled, now I ask the user to enter the policy number and an issuance office (which is a dropdown), and it is being read in the database, so when the data provided by the user, the textboxes are enabled, now, when the user clicks on the right issuance office on the drop down list (selected index changed) it searches the records on the database, now i want to prompt the user on selected index change, a message box that would show ("Please wait while we search your record") and close the dialog box when its finish searching from the database.

Comment: nice question, but i have one doubt what if user cancels the message box while validation is still going on?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot do "Message boxes" like you are thinking. you would need to use a modal popup dialog which ASP.NET AJAX has:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

you can also use JQuery to achieve the same thing but it would be clientside based:

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

[How to use jquery blockUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276940/how-to-use-jquery-blockui)

This will do what you are wanting to.